# what is PCA effect on model performance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Scenario 1.   Orginal Model

```
pipe=Pipeline([  ('minmax', MinMaxScaler() )  ,  ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=100,n_estimators=100, random_state=1))])
cross_val_score(pipe, data[['lat', 'lon', 'a1', 'a2']],data['target'],scoring='r2', cv=5)
##Results: array([0.70712946, 0.73058919, 0.72816258, 0.71886931, 0.71670827])
```

Scenario 2.   Add noises into Model

```
data['noise1']=randn( data.shape[0])
data['noise2']=randn( data.shape[0])
data['noise3']=randn( data.shape[0])
data['noise4']=randn( data.shape[0])
data['noise5']=randn( data.shape[0])

pipe=Pipeline([  ('minmax', MinMaxScaler() )  ,  ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=100,n_estimators=100, random_state=1))])
cross_val_score(pipe, data[['lat', 'lon', 'a1', 'a2','noise1','noise2','noise3','noise4','noise5']], data['target'],scoring='r2', cv=5)
#results array([0.6811519 , 0.70208517, 0.69915057, 0.69729788, 0.69075629])
```

Scenario 3.   Add noises and PCA

```
pipe=Pipeline([  ('minmax', MinMaxScaler() ) , ('pca', PCA(n_components=4) ) ,  ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=100,n_estimators=100, random_state=1))])
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
mypred=pipe.predict(X_test)
cross_val_score(pipe, data[['lat', 'lon', 'a1', 'a2', 'noise1','noise2','noise3','noise4','noise5']], data['target'],scoring='r2', cv=5)
#results [0.2472771 , 0.3253291 , 0.32945281, 0.32811894, 0.33821924]
```

I create these three scenarios to simulate a modeling task. Basically, adding noise reduces the performance of RF. In order to remove noises, I used PCA.. but looks like the linearly uncorrelated dimension reduction is not very effective. Any suggestions for improvement? Many thanks

Comment: You should take a look at [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you ask good questions and make it more likely to get answers. Furthermore this seems to be off-topic for stackoverflow. Better ask this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions